# axios.get rendering with react table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to store the data from an axios.get into a variable and then pass it through a Table so that it can render the data onto the table.

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import fellar from "./prototypes/fakedata/fakedata-sem.json";
import TableLogic from "../components/grid-components/table";
import Sidebar from "../components/sidebar/sidebar";
import { GridBtn } from "../styles/ts-styling/button";
import { SemModal } from "../components/modal/modal";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Semesters() {
  const fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/semesters")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        const semdata = res.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const tablefetch = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/semesters')
      .then(
        response => setResultArray(response.data))
    }
    tablefetch();
  }, []);

  const [resultArray, setResultArray] = useState([]);
  // const data = useMemo(() => fellar, []);
  const data = useMemo(() => resultArray, [])
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const SemColumns = [
    {
      header: "Season",
      accessorKey: "season",
    },
    {
      header: "Year",
      accessorKey: "year",
    },
    {
      header: "Start Date",
      accessorKey: "start",
    },
    {
      header: "End Date",
      accessorKey: "end",
    },
  ];

  const handleSubmit = () => {};

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <h1>.</h1>
      {/* <GridBtn onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>
          Create New Semester
        </GridBtn> */}
      <GridBtn onClick={fetchData} />
      {modalOpen && (
        <SemModal
          closeModal={() => {
            setModalOpen(false);
          }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      )}
      <TableLogic data={data} columns={SemColumns} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Semesters;
```

but I haven't been able to render it properly, I have tried using the different variables in the useState, but it either ouputs an error, cannot find properties of undefined reading 'length'. Or just plain nothing. Which is the result of the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to fetch data from an API using Axios and then display that data in a table using the TableLogic component. The main issue here is that the data fetching is asynchronous, and you need to handle the state of the fetched data properly.
Created an async function fetchSemestersData to fetch data from the API using Axios. The fetched data is then stored in the resultArray state using setResultArray.

Used the useEffect hook to call the fetchSemestersData function when the component mounts, so it fetches the data and stores it in the state.

Passed resultArray as the data to be rendered in the table.

The modified code is here:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import TableLogic from "../components/grid-components/table";
import Sidebar from "../components/sidebar/sidebar";
import { GridBtn } from "../styles/ts-styling/button";
import { SemModal } from "../components/modal/modal";

function Semesters() {
  const [resultArray, setResultArray] = useState([]);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const fetchSemestersData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/semesters");
      setResultArray(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSemestersData();
  }, []);

  const SemColumns = [
    {
      header: "Season",
      accessorKey: "season",
    },
    {
      header: "Year",
      accessorKey: "year",
    },
    {
      header: "Start Date",
      accessorKey: "start",
    },
    {
      header: "End Date",
      accessorKey: "end",
    },
  ];

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // Handle form submission here
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <h1>.</h1>
      <GridBtn onClick={fetchSemestersData}>Fetch Data</GridBtn>
      {modalOpen && (
        <SemModal
          closeModal={() => {
            setModalOpen(false);
          }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      )}
      <TableLogic data={resultArray} columns={SemColumns} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Semesters;
```